# Itext - a5 page size is the vertical half of a4

Tags: pdf, itext, page-size

i'm trying to create a pdf that must be on a5 format ( the horizontal half on an a4 )

like [wikipedia source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:A_size_illustration2.svg&page=1) i need that my page size must be equals to the horizontal half of a4 but using this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

it creates me this:

[image]

But i need this:

[image]

(With all table inside rotated )

How can i fix? can someone help me? thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

iText in Action, 2nd Edition, in chapter 13 has an example which rotates all pages in a PDF file by 90 degrees. The sample source code is available as [RotatePages.java](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter13/RotatePages.java) in the SourceForge iText SVN repository.

Comment: ok.. it rotate me page.. but doesn't rotate me content... in my post i wrote, under the last image, (With all table inside rotated ).. so i have to rotate pdf and rotate content inside it..

Answer (score 1):

I solved simply in this way:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5.rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

So

```
PageSize.A5 generate a page which size is vertical half of A4

PageSize.A5.rotate() generate a page which size is horizontal half of A4
```

Comment: Ah, so all you needed was A5 landscape. Indeed, you can get that by rotating the A5 portrait page size. Alternatively you can directly define a PageSize instance with the desired dimensions without rotation. The resulting documents look identical but there are some minor differences which only matter if you later somehow have to reprocess the document.